# Etsy cURL to see ads

Tags: curl, wget, etsy

I'm trying to find out when my competitor has ads on and off as I think they may be doing something clever on timing their ads. When I go into Etsy on my browser, I can see "Ad by XXXXXX". I was planning to use curl to regularly check when they are/aren't doing ads but this ads section doesn't show up in curl but does in a browser.

Any ideas on why this is the case and how I can do regular checks?

Comment: They're likely shown by JS code, curl & wget doesn't execute them, you'll want selenium based solution that runs Chrome/Firefox

Comment: @Martheen Thanks, I'll look into that.